# datomic / datascript beginner - can we have multiple schemas

Tags: clojure, datomic, datascript

very basic question to get me started. Suppose I have a database of sales by country:

`[{:sales/country "CN" :sales/amount 1000 :sales/account "XYZ"} ...]`

I would like to also have a list of facts about each country something like:

`[{:country/short-name "CN" :country/long-name "China" ...}]`

And then do queries of the type "list all sales that happened in China (using the long-name)".

Is that one database? How do I make it clear there are two distinct schemas? Do I transact the first schema then the sales data, and later the country schema and data?

EDIT: sorry my question wasn't clear. Here is live example:

```
(d/transact! conn
             [{:country/code "BR" :country/name "Brazil"}
              {:country/code "CN" :country/name "China"}])

(d/transact! conn
             [{:sales/country "CN" :sales/amount 1000 :sales/account "XYZ"}
              {:sales/country "CN" :sales/amount 1000 :sales/account "AAA"}
              {:sales/country "BR" :sales/amount 1000 :sales/account "BBB"}}
              ])
```

I was able to run a query to join the tables and get the results I wanted. What I don't understand is what is best practice to define my schema. Is it just one schema or two of them, one for each table. Can I do this:

```
(def schema {:country/code {:db/valueType :db.type/string :db/unique :db.unique/identity}
             :country/name {:db/valueType :db.type/string}
             :sales/account {:db/valueType :db.type/string :db/unique :db.unique/identity}
             :sales/country-code {:db/valueType :db.type/string}
             :sales/amount {:db/valueType :db.type/integer}

             })
```

And is there a better way to define in the schema that country/code and sales/country-code are the same "key"?

Thanks,

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Thanks @cfrick but it's not failing - it's working actually. I'm just not sure this is the right design.

Comment: thank you @AlanThompson - added more details as to my design issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have 1 schema, but that should be enough. Use namespace in keywords to distinguish between different “domains” (`:country/*` for info about countries, `:sales/*` for info about sales).

Datomic is more of a column store, so any entity can have any attribute, and you can even mix different “tables” on a single attribute (I don’t recommend it, but it’s possible).

Your use of `:country/code` is what Datomic calls “an external id”. This is also a good practice, although, there’s no way to specify that `:sales/country` is a reference to `:country/code`.

What I suggest you do instead is make `:sales/country` a Datomic reference:

```
:sales/country-code {:db/valueType :db.type/ref}
```

and then link to it in transaction using lookup ref:

```
@(d/transact! conn [{:sales/country [:country/code "CN"] :sales/amount 1000 :sales/account "XYZ"})
```

This will make sure country with this code exist during transaction time. You’ll also get benefits like easy retrieving country info from sales using entities/pull.

Comment: Thank you, this is the explanation I was looking for! and thanks @Niki Tonsky for the great contributions to the Clojure community